# Saving XLSM as XLSX And Have Formulas Reference XLSX

Tags: excel, vba

I am working from an excel VBA Project, my project populates my sheets in the backgroud and saves as a xlsx, so i can latter open and review.

The Issue I am having is the cells still reference the Excel Vba project.  Is there a way to save workbook as XLSX and have it the cells reference the new workbook(XLSX) not the (XLSM)

this is the code i am using to save

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\asuchadu\Desktop\myFileName.xlsx"
Workbooks("myFileName.xlsx").Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the links before closing the new file, like this

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\asuchadu\Desktop\myFileName.xlsx"

With Workbooks("myFileName")

    If Not IsEmpty(.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)) Then
        .ChangeLink "myFileName.xlsm", "myFileName.xlsx", xlExcelLinks
    End If

    .Close True

End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: ok I realized the issue, When iam saving the sheets from the project I am actually only taking a portion.  I have 42 sheets within the project but need to only save 7 of those sheets.  An of those 7 sheets there linked to the original project.  So if i save all 42 sheets (which i don't want to) then the sheets save fine and links are no longer an issue.  So i was thinking of a work aroubnd is there a way to set new saved xlsx File as Application.calculation=xlmanul when saving,  itried to do this before saving but the new workbook still calculate automatically

Comment: Ok this is what i have got, I tried saving all 42 files as xlsx and i thought it was working but realized all my areas that have formulas =sheet1!A2 there all #NAME? now